# Running an existing Java project on Java N-IDE (Android)

Tags: java, android, ide

I try to run a simple Java console application on Java N-IDE on Android, but this app was initially developped on IntelliJ on Windows

I downloaded Termux, installed Git and cloned my project, worked like a charm.

I can open my project folder and see all my classes, I can open my Main class on a table and hit run, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "src.main.Main" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/storage/emulated/0/workspace/projectName/app/build/dexedClasses/classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]

    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

    at com.duy.android.compiler.java.Java.run(Java.java:91)

    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.executeDex(ExecuteActivity.java:147)

    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.exec(ExecuteActivity.java:124)

    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity.access$100(ExecuteActivity.java:45)

    at com.duy.ide.javaide.run.activities.ExecuteActivity$1.run(ExecuteActivity.java:88)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The fact is I don't find how to configure this "DexPathList"

The most accurate answer I found on Internet was there:

https://github.com/tranleduy2000/javaide/wiki/Open-java-example

But this tuto is about running an example code from the app, not about running another existing project

There's an interesting "Select class to run" menu on a screenshot but I don't know how to open it

Does anyone know how Java N-IDE works?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't apply in which
file from Storage or other known files,and extract the files
or just to add them,so it can open and maybe work perfectly fine.